# Getting no file or directory on starting terminal in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am getting the following message on terminal start

```
-bash: /home/abhineel/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm no expert on terminal, but it sounds to me as though you aren't opening terminal, strictly speaking, but a script which attempts to open a terminal with a particular set of commands.  

What happens if you press Ctrl-Alt-T ?

If you get a terminal window that works, and if you are satisfied with that, I recommend you use that instead of that script.

Answer (score 0):

Your "terminal start" is trying to execute `/home/abhineel/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, and either `/home/abhineel/.rvm/scripts/rvm` does not exist, or is not available to whatever user you're running as. `/home/abhineel/.rvm/scripts/rvm` is being called from your `~/.bashrc`, or other startup files (read `man bash` about startup files). Alternatively, `/home/abhineel/.rvm/scripts/rvm` does exist, but cannot find a file/directory it wants.